# PowerMock calls real method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to spy private method with PowerMock but on the line when I define the what should be returned when the private method is called, it calls the method and I am getting and Null Pointer Exception. What PowerMock is calling real method on this line ?

```
 myService= PowerMockito.spy(new MyService(myParam));

  .....
 PowerMockito.when(myService, "getCLientBy", anyString(), anyString(), anyString()).thenRetur`n(Client.of(setName, new HashSet<>())); // here it calls real method
```

Comment: Can you add more information about the class you are trying to test and the test itself? For example what are the parameters that are used by the real code when the method is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you prepare your class to be used in spy by adding `@PrepareForTest(MyService.class)`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// We prepare MyService for test because it's final 
// or we need to mock private or static methods
@PrepareForTest(MyService.class)
public class YourTestCase {

    //...

    @Test
    public void spyingWithPowerMock() {  

        MyService classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new MyService(myParam));

        //.....

        // use PowerMockito to set up your expectation
        PowerMockito.doReturn(Client.of(setName, new HashSet<>()))
            .when(classUnderTest, "getClientBy", anyString(), anyString(), anyString());



        //...
```

Also make sure provide the correct method name to be invoked.

Comment: I added  @PrepareForTest(MyService.class) but it still works the same. Also checked the method name.

Comment: @JoseTepedino was that explanation meant for me or the OP?

Comment: @Nkosi, it was meant for both you, but I've made mistake in the previous comment, as I was referring to Mockito; then I noticed that the problem was about spying a private method. I'm sorry. I've built a small simulation and posted it in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

@user1474111 and @Nkosi

I've built a small simulation of your example.
Maybe you also need to add the Client class in the PrepareForTest annotation.

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({ MyService.class, Client.class })
    public class Example1Test {

        @Test
        public void testPowerMockito() throws Exception {

            MyService myService = PowerMockito.spy(new MyService("myParam"));

            PowerMockito.when(myService, "getClientBy", ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).thenReturn(Client.of("setName", new HashSet<String>()));

            myService.run();

            Assert.assertEquals("setName", myService.getClient().getName());
        }
    }

    public class MyService {

        private Client client;

        public MyService(String param) { }

        private Client getClientBy(String a, String b, String c) {
            return new Client(a + b + c);
        }

        public Client getClient() {
            return this.client;
        }

        public void setClient(Client client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void run() {
            setClient(getClientBy("A", "B", "C"));
        }

    }

   public class Client {

        private final String name;

        public Client(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public static Client of(String name, HashSet<String> hashSet) {
            return new Client(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried to add it but result is the same. Actually i think something also wrong with design but cannot  change it at the moment.